# Need help for representing electric field

Tags: javascript, physics, trigonometry

I posted a similar question yesterday and I made changes that are getting me closer to representing the electric field.
There are 3 canvas, the canvas1(green charge), canvas2(blue charge) and the canvas3(resultant force).
If you want to see how it works in profundity here is the url:
https://mauriciolapi.github.io/proyectoFisica/

The real problem is that some arrows are not doing what i want

Math ecuations to find the direction of the resultant vector:

```
        let angleBetween;
        let anguloResultante;

        let alpha;
        let cosAlpha;
        let sinAlpha;
        let eR;
        
        
        //if the 2 charges are positve do all of this
        if(q1Value && q2Value > 0){
            //rotation of the canvas(electric arrows) 
            canvas1.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo1}deg)`;
            canvas2.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo2}deg)`;

            //Here im getting the angleBetween
            if(positivo1 > positivo2){
                angleBetween = positivo1 - positivo2;
                if(angleBetween > 180){
                    angleBetween = 360 - angleBetween ;
                }

                alpha = 180 - angleBetween;
                cosAlpha = Math.cos(alpha*Math.PI/180);
                sinAlpha = Math.sin(alpha*Math.PI/180);
                eR = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e1,2) + Math.pow(e2,2) - 2*e1*e2*cosAlpha)
                anguloResultante = (Math.asin(sinAlpha/eR)*e1) * 180 / Math.PI;

                if(positivo1 > 0 && positivo1 < 90){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante}deg)`;
                }
                if(positivo1 > 90 && positivo1 < 180){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+90}deg)`;
                }
                if(positivo1 > 180 && positivo1 < 270){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+180}deg)`;
                }
                if(positivo1 > 270){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+270}deg)`;
                }
            }
            
            //Here im getting the angleBetween
            if(positivo2 > positivo1){
                angleBetween = positivo2 - positivo1;
                if(angleBetween > 180){
                    angleBetween = 360 - angleBetween ;
                }


                alpha = 180 - angleBetween;
                cosAlpha = Math.cos(alpha*Math.PI/180);
                sinAlpha = Math.sin(alpha*Math.PI/180);
                eR = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e1,2) + Math.pow(e2,2) - 2*e1*e2*cosAlpha)
                anguloResultante = (Math.asin(sinAlpha/eR)*e2) * 180 / Math.PI;

                if(positivo2 > 0 && positivo2 < 90){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante}deg)`;
                }
                if(positivo2 > 90 && positivo2 < 180){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+90}deg)`;
                }
                if(positivo2 > 180 && positivo2 < 270){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+180}deg)`;
                }
                if(positivo2 > 270){
                    canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+270}deg)`;
                }
            }
```

FULL FUNCTION

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=> {
        
    let distanceX = getDistanceBetweenElements(canvas1, x)/100;
    let distanceY = getDistanceBetweenElements(canvas1, y)/100;
    
    let e1 = (k*q1)/Math.pow(distanceX,2);
    let e2 = (k*q2)/Math.pow(distanceY,2);

    let Q1x = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('x')).x;
    let Q1y = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('x')).y;
    let Q2x = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('y')).x;
    let Q2y = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('y')).y;
    
    const rekt = canvas1.getBoundingClientRect();
    const anchorX= rekt.left + rekt.width / 2;
    const anchorY= rekt.top + rekt.height / 2; 
    
    let angleDeg1 = angle(Q1x, Q1y, anchorX, anchorY);
    let angleDeg2 = angle(Q2x, Q2y, anchorX, anchorY);
        
    let positivo1 = angleDeg1+180;
    let negativo1 = angleDeg1;

    let positivo2 = angleDeg2 + 180;
    let negativo2 = angleDeg2;
    
    let angleBetween;
    let anguloResultante;

    let alpha;
    let cosAlpha;
    let sinAlpha;
    let eR;
    
    if(q1Value && q2Value > 0){
        canvas1.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo1}deg)`;
        canvas2.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo2}deg)`;

        if(positivo1 > positivo2){
            angleBetween = positivo1 - positivo2;
            if(angleBetween > 180){
                angleBetween = 360 - angleBetween ;
            }

            alpha = 180 - angleBetween;
            cosAlpha = Math.cos(alpha*Math.PI/180);
            sinAlpha = Math.sin(alpha*Math.PI/180);
            eR = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e1,2) + Math.pow(e2,2) - 2*e1*e2*cosAlpha)
            anguloResultante = (Math.asin(sinAlpha/eR)*e1) * 180 / Math.PI;

            if(positivo1 > 0 && positivo1 < 90){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante}deg)`;
            }
            if(positivo1 > 90 && positivo1 < 180){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+90}deg)`;
            }
            if(positivo1 > 180 && positivo1 < 270){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+180}deg)`;
            }
            if(positivo1 > 270){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+270}deg)`;
            }
        }
        
        if(positivo2 > positivo1){
            angleBetween = positivo2 - positivo1;
            if(angleBetween > 180){
                angleBetween = 360 - angleBetween ;
            }

            alpha = 180 - angleBetween;
            cosAlpha = Math.cos(alpha*Math.PI/180);
            sinAlpha = Math.sin(alpha*Math.PI/180);
            eR = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e1,2) + Math.pow(e2,2) - 2*e1*e2*cosAlpha)
            anguloResultante = (Math.asin(sinAlpha/eR)*e2) * 180 / Math.PI;

            if(positivo2 > 0 && positivo2 < 90){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante}deg)`;
            }
            if(positivo2 > 90 && positivo2 < 180){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+90}deg)`;
            }
            if(positivo2 > 180 && positivo2 < 270){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+180}deg)`;
            }
            if(positivo2 > 270){
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante+270}deg)`;
            }
        }


    }
    if(q1Value && q2Value < 0){
        canvas1.style.transform = `rotate(${negativo1}deg)`;
        canvas2.style.transform = `rotate(${negativo2}deg)`;
    }
    if(q1Value > 0 && q2Value < 0){
        canvas1.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo1}deg)`;
        canvas2.style.transform = `rotate(${negativo2}deg)`;
    }
    if(q1Value < 0 && q2Value > 0){
        canvas1.style.transform = `rotate(${negativo1}deg)`;
        canvas2.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo2}deg)`;
    }
    
});



btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    q1Value = document.getElementById('valor1').value;
    q1Potencia = document.getElementById('potencia1').value;
    q1Prefijo = document.getElementById('prefijo1').value;

    q2Value = document.getElementById('valor2').value;
    q2Potencia = document.getElementById('potencia2').value;
    q2Prefijo = document.getElementById('prefijo2').value;

    if(q1Value > 0 || q1Value < 0){
        if(q1Prefijo == '1'){
            q1 = q1Value * Math.pow(10, q1Potencia);
        }else if(q1Prefijo == '2'){
            q1 = (q1Value * Math.pow(10, q1Potencia)) / 1e+6;
        }else if(q1Prefijo == '3'){
            q1 = (q1Value * Math.pow(10, q1Potencia)) / 1e+12;
        }else if(q1Prefijo == '4'){
            q1 = (q1Value * Math.pow(10, q1Potencia)) / 1e+9;
        }
    }

    if(q2Value > 0 || q2Value < 0){
        if(q2Prefijo == '1'){
            q2 = q2Value * Math.pow(10, q2Potencia);
        }else if(q2Prefijo == '2'){
            q2 = (q2Value * Math.pow(10, q2Potencia)) / 1e+6;
        }else if(q2Prefijo == '3'){
            q2 = (q2Value * Math.pow(10, q2Potencia)) / 1e+12;
        }else if(q2Prefijo == '4'){
            q2 = (q2Value * Math.pow(10, q2Potencia)) / 1e+9;
        }
    }


    //makes q1 and q2 dragabbles
    const dragX = (e) =>{
        x.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
        x.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';  
    }

    x.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", dragX);
    });
        
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", dragX);
    });

    const dragY = (e) =>{
        y.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
        y.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';  
    }

    y.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", dragY);
    });
        
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", dragY);
    });

    //Accion createArrow
    for(let i = 0; i < 104; i++) {
        createArrow();
    }


});
```

Comment: Can you post your full function?

Comment: I post it for you, but you can inspect the source of the web page